# TOMEEE - Can't lookup ejb

Tags: java, jms, ejb, apache-tomee

I have implemented a basic EJB Object in my code. Then I created a jar for this ejb. The jar file contains:

1. package containing the ejb classes (home interface/remote bean interface/bean implementaion)
2. META-INF folder containing the ejb-jar.xml

ejb-jar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">
<ejb-jar>
  <display-name>NewTransactionEjb</display-name>
  <enterprise-beans>
    <session>
      <display-name>NewTransactionEjb</display-name>
      <ejb-name>NewTransactionEjb</ejb-name>
      <home>gr.cosmote.mdb.NewTransactionEjb.NewTransactionEjbHome</home>
      <remote>gr.cosmote.mdb.NewTransactionEjb.NewTransactionEjb</remote>
      <ejb-class>gr.cosmote.mdb.NewTransactionEjb.NewTransactionEjbBean</ejb-class>
      <session-type>Stateless</session-type>
      <transaction-type>Container</transaction-type>
    </session>
  </enterprise-beans>
  <assembly-descriptor>
    <container-transaction>
      <method>
        <ejb-name>NewTransactionEjb</ejb-name>
        <method-name>*</method-name>
      </method>
      <trans-attribute>NotSupported</trans-attribute>
    </container-transaction>
  </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>
```

Then I deployed the EJB by placing the jar in webapps folder and from the server logs it seems to have been deployed successfully.
But when I try to reference the ejb from my code I get error.
Code:

```
Properties p = new Properties();
                   p.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.apache.openejb.core.LocalInitialContextFactory");
                   InitialContext context = new InitialContext(p);
                   ejbHome = (EJBHome) context.lookup("java:global/NewTransactionEjb/NewTransactionEjb");
```

I have used "java:global/NewTransactionEjb/NewTransactionEjb" because upon ejb deployment I see this line in the server logs:

```
03-Sep-2021 17:31:23.628 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.JndiBuilder.bind Jndi(name=global/NewTransactionEjb/NewTransactionEjb!gr.cosmote.mdb.NewTransactionEjb.NewTransactionEjbHome) 
--> Ejb(deployment-id=NewTransactionEjb)
```

In the execution it seems the the above code is working and it retrieves the EJBHome, but when I try to
cast it to my own home interface class it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy362 cannot be cast to
gr.cosmote.mdb.NewTransactionEjb.NewTransactionEjbHome
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found the solution to this issue. To be precise the actual problem has nothing to do with the exception which is just confusing. So I will mention my problem anyway, in case someone faces the same issue.

My problem was that 2 of the EJB classes (home interface and remote bean interface) were also in TOMEE /lib directory except for the EJB deployable jar file which was placed in /webapps directory. So I removed them from the jar file (now it contains only the bean implementaion class), deployed it and everything is working fine.